# how to send info from php to c++ using exec?

Tags: php, c++, exec

i need to send info from php to c++ using `exec` but i can't and don't know why this not work
i used too `escapeshellcmd()` but nothing change

```
<?php
$a=2; // here 1st value
$b=3; // here 2nd value
exec("project $a $b", $out); // here $a and $b should send the info to project but it's the problem
print_r($out); // here i use print_r to general use as some time the info be as array and echo won't print it
?>
```

i see the result

```
Array ( [0] => -858993460-858993460 )
-858993460
```

is default value to `int` type

Comment: is project is in same path as of php root directory for e.g. if your file is in /var/www/html than project should also be in the same path until path of project is globally accessible

Comment: And you're sure that's not just the output from the `project` executable?

Comment: Check for permission that does your C program can be run by your apache user?

Comment: i'm sure 100% that the program is running well and if get the values will print it

Answer (score 0):

maybe this'll work for you:

```
exec("project.exe {$a} {$b}", $out);
```